# how to check the radio button is checked or not in windows form

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have 3 pair of radiobutton at my form I want to check at every group of radiobutton one radiobutton is checked when user press save button. I used the below code to check every radiobutton, but I think this one a better approach to check.

```
if (radioBttnAddrssCoYes.Checked || rdoBttnAddCorrectNo.Checked)
{
    if (rdoGroundFloorTrue.Checked || radioGroundFFalse.Checked)
    {
        if (rdoHomeTrue.Checked || radioMeet.Checked)
        {
            // Here I do something
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please check Customer All day At Home");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Check Ground Floor Delivery");
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Check Addresss Correct"); 
}
```

[image: Below is my form for better understanding]

Thanks For your support and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do it a little different, but it doesn't mean your way is wrong.

```
if(VaildateRadioGroupIsChecked(radioBttnAddrssCoYes, rdoBttnAddCorrectNo, "Check Addresss Correct") && 
   VaildateRadioGroupIsChecked(rdoGroundFloorTrue, radioGroundFFalse, "Please Check Ground Floor Delivery") && 
   VaildateRadioGroupIsChecked(rdoHomeTrue, radioMeet, "Please check Customer All day At Home")) 
{
    // do your thing...
}

private bool VaildateRadioGroupIsChecked(RadioButton a, RadioButton b, string MessageToUser) 
{
    if(!a.Checked && !b.Checked) {
        Messagebox.Show(MessageToUser);
        return false;
    }
return true;
}
```

Of course, you can develop it further and not send the 2 radio buttons to the function, but it's containing element. this way, if you have 3, 4, or n radio buttons you can check all of them in one simple call.

Another well known technique to validate that a radio box is checked is to simply hold a boolean variable on the form level that is false by default, and changed to true when any of the radio buttons is checked. However, this technique will not serve you well in this case, since you will need 3 boolean variables for that, and the code will be unnecessary complicated comparing to the other solutions.

To answer your question in the comment, I would probably do something like that:

```
string MessageToUser = VaildateRadioGroupIsChecked(radioBttnAddrssCoYes, rdoBttnAddCorrectNo, "Check Addresss Correct") + 
                       VaildateRadioGroupIsChecked(rdoGroundFloorTrue, radioGroundFFalse, "Please Check Ground Floor Delivery") +  
                       VaildateRadioGroupIsChecked(rdoHomeTrue, radioMeet, "Please check Customer All day At Home");

if(MessageToUser.Length == 0) {
    // do your stuff
} else {
    Messagebox.Show(MessageToUser);
}

private string VaildateRadioGroupIsChecked(RadioButton a, RadioButton b, string MessageToUser) 
{
    if(!a.Checked && !b.Checked) {
        return MessageToUser + "\n";
    }
return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: i like your approach i want to show the user all message once like "Check Ground Floor" in New Line "Please check Customer All day At Home" all message once how this can be done

Comment: Again, there are several ways to do it. see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite it to the following if you find it more readable and want to display custom messages to the User when some radios of a group are not checked.

```
if (! (rdoHomeTrue.Checked || radioMeet.Checked)) {
  MessageBox.Show("Please check Customer All day At Home");
  return;
}

if (! (rdoGroundFloorTrue.Checked || radioGroundFFalse.Checked)) {
  MessageBox.Show("Please Check Ground Floor Delivery");
  return;
}

if (! (radioBttnAddrssCoYes.Checked || rdoBttnAddCorrectNo.Checked)) {
   MessageBox.Show("Check Addresss Correct"); 
   return;
}

// here i do something
```